# CsvReader - adding data into sqlite

Tags: sqlite, csv, lumenworks

am new to all of this, but a fast learning curve is underway.

I have been searching round, but cannot piece together what I need.

I am using Lumenworks CsvReader to reader the data from a csv file - so far so good, and I am seeing data. Next I need to pass this data into SQLite.

Where I am stuck is trying to pass that information into my INSERT statement in a loop, so hoping someone here can help me?

I know the error lies in my loop, (and I know the format may be wrong), but I cannot figure this out. Thankyou for any help in advance.

here is my code so far:

```
    command.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE [Test] ([Code] VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , [Description] VARCHAR(100),[RRP] NUMERIC DEFAULT (null) ,[Points] NUMERIC, [Buy] NUMERIC DEFAULT (null) )";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    string insertText = "INSERT INTO [Test] ([Code],[Description],[RRP],[Points],[Buy]) VALUES(@Code,@Description,@RRP,@Points,@Buy)";

        SQLiteTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
        command.Transaction = trans;

        command.CommandText = insertText;

        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(@"C:\Data.csv"), true))
        {
            int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;

            string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();

            while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", csv[i]);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", csv[i]);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RRP", csv[i]);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Points", csv[i]);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Buy", csv[i]);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: i get an SQLiteException now when executing the command, with the detail of 'constraint failed', this is duw to the AddWithValue section, as i know i have the wrong syntax for csv[i]..but my knowledge is too limited to know what to put in there instead.

Comment: Please tell us which CSV column should go into which parameter.

Comment: Hi CL - should all be in order - so column 1 into Code, 2 into Description, 3 into RRP, 4 into Points, 5 into Buy. - Thanks for taking the time to look at this.